# How to make one element in a numpy array share the same memory address with another element in a different numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays

Is it possible to make one element in a numpy array share the same memory address with another element in a different numpy array, so that if I change one, the other element in the other numpy array changes?

```
a = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 4) #[0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.3]
b = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 4) #[0.4, 0.7, 0.8, 0.1]
#let b[0] = a[0]
b[0] = a[0] # b[0] = 0.2 and a[0] = 0.2
```

If I change `b[0]`, I want `a[0]` to also change. How do I do that?

Comment: No, unless it's the first and last element or similar special case. Please post a complete example that's representative of what you have in mind

Comment: If this is what you want, you should consider using lists of mutable types instead of numpy arrays.

Comment: I guess my answer contradicts the original comment, but a specific example is still requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, yes, although it's not practical to do so. Here is an example:

```
buffer = np.zeros((5, 7))
a = buffer[::2, ::3]
b = buffer[1:4, 3:6]
```

By adjusting the strides of `a` to step around `b`, you've created a pair of arrays such that `a[1, 1]` is at the same memory address as `b[1, 0]`, but none of the other elements are shared between then.

This wastes a lot of memory and slows things down, since the arrays can't be contiguous in the general case.

The example you added to the question is simpler to handle:

```
buffer = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 7)
a = buffer[4::-1]
b = buffer[4:]
```

The wasteful approach to the same would be

```
buffer = np.empty(15)
a = buffer[:4]
b = buffer[::4]
a[:] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 4)
b[:] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 4)
```

In general though, I'd recommend using a property on an array subclass or something like that.

Comment: Your use of double colon in slicing is making it difficult for me to understand your examples. Can you please change it to single colons? Thank you.

Comment: @EarthIsFlat you can visualize the strides by starting with `buffer = np.arange(35).reshape((5, 7))`

Comment: @EarthIsFlat. Not possible. A slice goes `start:stop:step`. Nothing I can do about that. `::3` for example means "take every third element"

Comment: Can you please make a class or a function that takes two arrays and maps the specified index element of the first array to the specified index element of the second array, so the two elements in the two different arrays have shared memory addresses? Please if you do this, I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @EarthIsFlat. This is not a free coding service. If you take the time to understand my examples, you will have no trouble writing such a function. If you run into specific questions along the way, please ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

```
  import numpy as np
  arr =np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
  int_arr1 = arr.astype(int)
  for i in range(len(int_arr1)):
    print("The Element", int_arr1[i] , " Memory Location :",int_arr1[i].data)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).